# Evaluate $ \ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (3x)}{x^2 +4}\,dx \ $ using Jordan's Lemma

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, trigonometry

How to to evaluate 
$
\
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (3x)}{x^2 +4}\,dx 
\
$ using Jordan's Lemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
Consider the complex integral

$$ \int_{C} \frac{ z\,{\rm e}^{3 i z}  }{ (z^2 + 4)} dz \,.$$

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) for the contour $C$.